# k-dependent oriented percolation system with small closure

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, percolation

I am studying the next result

> Let $\Gamma=\{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}\times\mathbb{Z}\text{ such that }
> > m+n \text{ even }\}$, $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\Gamma}$, and $\mathcal{F}$ the
>   $\sigma$-algebra generated by the cylinder sets of $\Omega$. We say
>   that  $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a k-dependent oriented
>   percolation system with closure bellow $\gamma$ if:
>   $$\mathbb{P}(\Psi(m_i,n)=0, \forall i \hspace{0.2cm}1\leq i\leq
> > r|\{\Psi(m,s), 0\leq s<n, (m,s)\in \Gamma\})< {\gamma}^{r}$$ where
>   $|m_i-m_j|>2k$ for $i \neq j$.

Theorem 1:
$\text{ Fix } k\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } 0<p<1. \text{ There exist } \gamma>0 \text{ such that for all  k-dependent oriented percolation system with closure bellow } \gamma$,  $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}) ,    \mathbb{P} \text{ is stochastically over }\mathbb{P}_{p}=\prod_{\Gamma} (p\delta_1+(1-p)\delta_0) $

I know that Theorem 1 follows from the Theorem 0.0 of [Liggett-Schonmann-Stacey], but I don't understand how.

Theorem 0.0:
For each $d$ and $k$, when $p$ is large enough, the random fields in $C(d,k,p)$ are dominated from bellow by the product random field with density $\rho$, where $\rho$ is a positive constant depending on $d$, $k$ and $p$. One can make the density of these product random fields become arbitrarily close to 1 by taking $p$ large enough.

Here $C(d,k,p)$ is the class of random fields $(X_s)_{s\in\mathbb{Z}}$ which have the property that for each $s\in\mathbb{Z}^{d}$, the conditional probability that $X_s=1$ given any information about the values of the $X_u$ for indices $u$ which are at a distance larger than $k$ from $s$ is bounded from bellow by $p$.

[Liggett-Schonmann-Stacey]Liggett, Thomas M., Roberto H. Schonmann, and Alan M. Stacey. "Domination by product measures." The Annals of Probability 25.1 (1997): 71-95.

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise about your sources and definitions.